# Access to localStorage from createApi RTK on first page load

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a case where I need to read my `.env` file on page load and if there is a specific value then I dispatch that value in my store, where I have `createApi` => `baseUrl` needs to access to that value, or localStorage, in order to use it as making an api call, here is an example of my code:

App.tsx

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
    const myCustomEndpoint = window._env_.MYENDPOINT;
    if(myCustomEndpoint) {
      dispatch(setApiEndpoint(myCustomEndpoint));
    }
}, [])
```

src/redux/reducerSlice.ts

```
export const reducerSlice = createSlice({
//...more slices
   setApiEndpoint: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.apiEndpoint = action.payload;
      localStorage.removeItem('api');
      localStorage.setItem('api', state.apiEndpoint);
    }
})
```

src/services/api.ts

```
const baseUrl = localStorage.getItem(config.apiEndpoint) || '';
export const dataApis = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'dataApis',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }), // here I cannot get the API for first time the page load
endpoints: (builder) => ({
 // my endpoints
})
```

So is there a way how to access the localStorage of the api endpoint which I have set for the first time my app was loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the endpoint directly in the `createApi` method, so just use like this for example: `fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: window._env_.MYENDPOINT || '' })`.

Comment: Thanks for your anser, but I have thought about this, and if I'm gonna use it, then the api its not going to be dynamic, so I won't change it when I want, also I won't be able to store it in localStorage properly